# Git status showing the same files even when I open git in another folder

Tags: git

I'm trying to git bash at a specific folder however when I open git bash and do git status, I don't see the contents of current folder but contents of previous folder. It's as if git isn't navigating away from that folder.

The path for git path is changing but not the contents.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `git status` shows the status of the repo in total, not just the folder you're in

Comment: The git status isn't showing files of current folder I opened git bash in. Thus the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `git status`, it shows *all* status changes regardless of whether you're in the root directory or a sub-directory.

If you only want to see the changes of the current folder, you can run:

```
git status .
```

And if you want to show the diff of any folder, you can run:

```
git status path/to/subfolder
```

Of course, all the above commands are only possible inside a git repo folder or its subfolders.

Comment: _"If you run git status, it shows all diffs regardless of your current directory."_ ... what?

Comment: I meant all diffs of the repo regardless of the sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you post more details about your issue, like what you did in more detail and what exactly shows you.

This folder you mention, meant to be a repository, right? Is it a cloned one, or an initiated one? There is a good possibility that Git Bash does not recognize the folder as a repository. If the folder is not a cloned repository, then you might wish to run `git init` inside the folder, in case it is not initiated.
If the repository is cloned, you might wish to delete the folder and re-clone it.

While you mentioned that you checked the path. before you do anything drastic, it is a good idea to double check your path to make sure that you are in the correct folder.

Good luck!